# how to get list of users by Role in spring?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

i'm using spring boot , Hibernate ,JPA repository , and i want to get list of users by role .

i have two entities

AppUser.java

```
 @Entity
 @Data
 @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
 public class AppUser implements Serializable
 {
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;
   @Column(unique = true)
   private String username;
   private String password;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private Collection<AppRole> roles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

AppRole.java

```
    @Entity
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class AppRole implements Serializable
    {
      @Id @GeneratedValue
      private Long id;
      private String roleName;
   }
```

and the JPaRepository

```
 public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<AppUser,Long>
 {

    public AppUser findByUsername(String username);

    @Query( "select u from AppUser u inner join u.AppRole r where r.role_name in :roles" )
   List<User> findBySpecificRoles(@Param("roles") AppRole roles);
}
```

i tried this query but it doesn't work as well as i want , it returns even the users who have other roles such as admin .

thank you for help in advance .

Comment: What it is the type of roles, you don't define the type, see that!? is it a list or just one role of type AppRole?

Comment: @YCF_L it's just a mistake , i have edited the code now , it's only one role of type AppRole .

Comment: now you have to replace `r.role_name in :roles` with `r = :roles`

Comment: @YCF_L : while debugging the project i get an exception : "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: AppRole of: interv.Entities.AppUser [select u from interv.Entities.AppUser u inner join u.AppRole r where r = :roles]
"

Comment: Tables in database are created with these names : app_user and app_role

Comment: Read the error message. It's crystal clear. It tells you that there is no property named AppRole in the class User. And indeed, the property is named `roles`. And once again, fix your naming. The argument of the query is **one** role. There's no reason to name it `roles` with a final `s`. That only makes things confusing. Similarly, the method should be named `findBySpecificRole`, since it expects **one** role, and not several ones.

Comment: @JBNizet yes you're absolutely right , but i have the same problem , i get a liste of users who have more than the role in the query , what should i do ?

Comment: Of course you get users who have more than that role, since you were looking for users having that role. Having a role doesn't mean "having a role and no other role". That problem is radically different from your previous problem, which was an exception due to an invalid query. To solve this new problem, you need to add a where clause to your query, such as `and size(u.roles) = 1`.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you so much this works now , i have one more question please , before using the system of Role/User i used 3 entities (Admin,manager,Client) , and in the UML classes Admin supposed to have a mapping of one to many / one to many with the entity Client , but now as i have only one entity which is User how i'm supposed to do the mapping while there is no entity Client now ?

Comment: I don't know what you're supposed to do, but if some users (admin) are the administrators for some other users (clients), and you want to keep that design, then you need a OneToMany between User and User.

Comment: ah i see  , yes this is what i want , the admin manages the client in the database , he can add a client or even remove it , thank you for your help , i appreciate this .

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `inner join` with `JOIN FETCH` and the query param `AppRole` by the field `roleName` like this :

```
@Query( "select u from AppUser u JOIN FETCH u.AppRole r where r.role_name = :roleName" )
List<User> findBySpecificRoles(@Param("roleName") String roleName);
```